# Error when trying to save gamedata

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, plist

I'm trying to save game data

```
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        // create an empty file if it doesn't exist
        if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultFile", ofType: "plist") {
            fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path)
        }
    }
```

But got error: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.

That variant should be working in Swift, but not Swift2..
How code can be modified?

Comment: If you need further advice, just write me a comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Swifts new try catch

```
if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {
    // create an empty file if it doesn't exist
    if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultFile", ofType: "plist") {
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path)
        } catch {
            //Catch Error Here
        }

    }
}
```

This should solve you problem, if not just write me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Th reason for the error

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try'

is because, the method

```
public func copyItemAtPath(srcPath: String, toPath dstPath: String) throws
```

indicates that the method that you are using can throw error(See the throws keyword?) so compiler instructs you to catch the error using swift try catch method

```
if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
// create an empty file if it doesn't exist
if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultFile", ofType: "plist") {
             do  {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle, toPath: path)
             }
             catch {
                //Catch error here
             }
        }
    }
```